# Scripted command line with redirection fails

Tags: linux, bash, script, redirection

The following works from the command line, but fails as script:

```
gunzip -c /disk1/hadoop/gunzip_tmp/in/part-00006.gz >> /disk1/hadoop/gunzip_tmp/outfile.000
```

The following script lines:

```
UZPCMD="gunzip -c "$TMPDIR"/in/"$FILEONLY" >> "$TMPDIR"/outfile.000"
echo $TMPDIR
echo $FILEONLY
echo $UZPCMD
```

produce the following output - the gunzip command line looks as it should:

```
/disk1/hadoop/gunzip_tmp
part-00006.gz
gunzip -c /disk1/hadoop/gunzip_tmp/in/part-00006.gz >> /disk1/hadoop/gunzip_tmp/outfile.000
```

However, issuing the command line from the script:

```
$UZPCMD
```

sends line after line of the unzipped file to stdout (as if the redirection were being ignored).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot specify the redirection as part of the variable string value.

The shell does some additional evaluation on input when you enter something directly on the command line, and that doesn't happen for string values. `>>` is just another argument to `gunzip`.

```
$ CMD="echo >> foo"
$ $CMD
>> foo
```

---

You can use `eval` instead. In the example, `eval $CMD` would correctly redirect `echo` output to the file `foo`. Note that this can introduce problems with unexpected input.

Comment: eval $UZPCMD worked like a charm. Thanks, Daniel!

Comment: @MarkP: in general, you should enclose variable substitutions in double-quotes to prevent unwanted extra parsing, e.g. `UZPCMD="gunzip -c $TMPDIR/in/$FILEONLY >> $TMPDIR/outfile.000"` and `eval "$UZPCMD"` -- it doesn't matter in this particular case, but is a good habit to get into.